# Fully erase/delete disk with a live debian disto

Tags: debian

Is it possible to do a full format of a disk with a live debian usb?
I mean really destroy all the data on the disk so that even data recovery tools can not get the data back in any way?

I have tried windows xp full format but apparently, with a little experience, the data can be retrieved anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's `shred`'s job. For instance...

```
$ shred -vz /dev/sda # DO NOT RUN THIS!
```

... will erase `/dev/sda` by:

- Writing 3 layers of random bytes to `/dev/sda`.
- Writing a final zero layer to `/dev/sda`.

Note that for most usages, a random pass is enough. You might want to go with a final zero pass, but passing 10 times is completely useless.

```
$ shred -zn1 /dev/sda # DO NOT RUN THIS EITHER!
```

For more information, see [`shred`'s man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shred%201). And for heaven's sake, **please double-check every single command you type which involves this tool**, otherwise you'll become yet another *"I've accidentaly erased by entire system, how can I fix this?"* question on this site.

Also note that this erases all data, including filesystem data. You'll have to format your disk once again after you've run this. The same applies if you use `shred` on a single partition (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) instead of a disk. This re-formatting can be done through `gparted`, or `fdisk` on the command-line. For more information on that:

- [Hard Disk Upgrade Mini How-To](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hard-Disk-Upgrade/partition.html), see *Partition the new disk* and *Format the new disk*.
- [Linux Hard Disk Format Command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disk-format/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Often times I need to install a new os on a disk and erase the old data in a way that it can never be brought back again.

Comment: Note that this is a *necessary step* if your new system has encrypted drives attached to it. ;)

Comment: I've tried so many things that didn't work after all and many ways invloves 2 hdd's and so on.. This method works spotless :-)